# Z3 java bindings?

Tags: java, z3

is the information on this page still up to date?

http://leodemoura.github.io/blog/2012/12/10/z3-for-java.html

I see that both rc and stable have a examples/java folder with an actual example,

does it mean that java bindings are now part of the stable/rc branch?

How can I enable and build them?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Java bindings are now (as of the 4.3.2 release) part of Z3. For documentation you might want to look at the comments in the Java source code. However, there is still an open issue regarding memory leaks (see [this codeplex issue](http://z3.codeplex.com/workitem/167)).
The build instructions on [de Mouras Blog](http://leodemoura.github.io/blog/2012/12/10/z3-for-java.html) are a bit out-of-date it seems i.e., you do not need to pass "--java" to mk_make, building the java bindings is the new default (but there is a "--nojava" option it seems). So you have:

1. python scripts/mk_make.py
2. cd build
3. make all

I should add that you can download prebuild packages on the Z3 codeplex download page (see the panel on the right and switch to "planned" if you are not a Windows user or want the latest unstable branch) which contain the Java bindings.